# Add attachments to Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar

Is it possible to add attachments (like photos) to Calendar events?

For example, I gathered the flyer of an event I want to attend. It is far in September, and having added the event to remember about it, I'd like to attach the picture I've taken of said flyer.

I don't know if the problem is the Italian version of Calendar, but I can't find the "Add Attachment" link - it is missing while editing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/416828/link-file-to-ical-event/416834#416834). It appears that attachments can be added to local calendars only. It may also be possible with calendars synced with remote servers, if the server supports it (but that's just a speculation, I don't know if such servers exist)

Comment: Mine are google-calendar synced. This must be the problem :/

Comment: Try to create a local calendar; if you can add attachment to it, then that's the problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just click on "Add Attachement" in the Calendar Entry Detail.

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see it in Calendar for Mountain Lion...

Comment: @pistacchio, it's there though. Did you click "Edit"?